# Removing Extra spaces in Python using a variable in 'for' Loop

Tags: python, loops

In a code:

```
a = 6
for i in range(a):
    print("case #",i)
```

While printing the output, as shown below:

```
case # 0
case # 1
case # 2
case # 3
case # 4
case # 5
```

There is an extra space between '#' and the variable 'i'.
How to remove this space?
In fact, if we normally write:

```
a = 'sam'
print("hello",a)
```

then also, the output is:

```
hello sam
```

there is an extra space between "hello" and "sam". How to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print("hello",a , sep='')
```

`sep` is the separator of print function when you call in with more that one argument.

Comment: that's a great answer, actually, this remove spaces without converting them into the string

Comment: Thanks, if you find this answer helpful please vote up and check the green one beside.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make one string from the two arguments, using `+`. Note: you have to convert `i` to string first.

```
a = 6
for i in range(a):
    print("case #"+str(i))
```

Comment: what is +str(i) here?

Comment: `+` 'merges' the two strings into one string, but your `i` is an integer in the beginning, so I use `str()` function to convert it to a string first

Comment: @VIKASRATHEE, vikas to thank anyone on SO or encourage people who are trying to help you on SO you could give their answers up votes and try to select 1 of the answer as correct too(after sometime when you see few answers are there for you question).

Comment: yes, of course, I do so...

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following too once.

```
a=6
for i in range(a):
   print 'case #%d' % (i)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
case #0
case #1
case #2
case #3
case #4
case #5
```

Comment: can you please explain this " '%d' % (i)"